# Problems running REST example from Project Wonder wiki

Tags: eclipse, rest, webobjects

I am new to Project Wonder and I am trying to run the second example in the tutorial, using REST. Even after adding the simple code to the Author and BlogEntry classes, I run into problems:

> ERChangeNotification: Initializing ERChangeNotification framework
>   [2015-8-11 14:23:30 CEST]  A fatal exception occurred:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/exolab/core/util/URI$MalformedURIException [2015-8-11 14:23:30
>   CEST]  com.webobjects.foundation.NSForwardException
>   [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError]
>   org/exolab/core/util/URI$MalformedURIException:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/exolab/core/util/URI$MalformedURIException    at
>   com.webobjects.foundation.NSForwardException._runtimeExceptionForThrowable(NSForwardException.java:43)
>     at
>   com.webobjects.foundation.NSSelector._safeInvokeMethod(NSSelector.java:124)
>     at
>   com.webobjects.foundation.NSNotificationCenter$_Entry.invokeMethod(NSNotificationCenter.java:588)
>     at
>   com.webobjects.foundation.NSNotificationCenter.postNotification(NSNotificationCenter.java:532)
>     at
>   com.webobjects.foundation.NSNotificationCenter.postNotification(NSNotificationCenter.java:546)
>     at
>   com.webobjects.appserver.WOApplication.run(WOApplication.java:1239)
>     at
>   com.webobjects.appserver.WOApplication.main(WOApplication.java:548)
>     at your.app.Application.main(Application.java:10) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/exolab/core/util/URI$MalformedURIException    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)   at
>   com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
>     at
>   com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
>     at
>   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:671)
>     at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)    at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.(InitialContext.java:216)   at
>   er.changenotification.ERCNConnectionKeeper.openConnection(ERCNConnectionKeeper.java:60)
>     at
>   er.changenotification.ERCNNotificationCoordinator.initialize(ERCNNotificationCoordinator.java:143)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.webobjects.foundation.NSSelector._safeInvokeMethod(NSSelector.java:122)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.exolab.core.util.URI$MalformedURIException    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 21 more

I imported the PW source as instructed in the wiki and put it in the build path. In case there were build problems I deleted all the frameworks and started all over again, but I am getting the same problem.

Comment: I seem to be making progress. There was probably a library conflict. I removed several unused libraries and it is going further.

I forgot to add that in the example in the wiki, when you click New, a REST project appears as one option. I don't have such an option and I am creating the project as a Project Wonder regular project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Seems there was some conflict with the libraries. I eliminated most of them and it started working. Thanks.